# expand $\det(I_n + hM)$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $M$ be Hermitian matrix and $h$ is a real number.

I am trying to expand $\det(I_n + hM)$. I found expansion of $\det(A)$ in terms of trace [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#Determinant_and_inverse_matrix). Substituting $A=I_n+hM$ and solving is a bit tedious. Is there a direct result available ?

Comment: Can you handle the special case where $M$ is diagonal?

Comment: Hint: Take a look at the eigenvalues of $I+hM$, or use the Schur decomposition of $M$.

Comment: Could the [Matrix Determinant Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) or [Weinstein–Aronszajn identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity) be useful perhaps?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz The eigenvalues of $I_n+hM$ are always positive (assume $h>0$). However I am not sure how to approach.

Comment: I found some results [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_determinant#Properties), but I am exactly not sure of the terminologies used. Can someone explain ?

Comment: Have you tried writing it out for $M = \pmatrix{2 & 0 \\ 0 & 5}$, for instance? What are the eigenvalues in this case? How do they appear in the expanded determinant? When you finish that, try $M = \pmatrix{2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3}$. By then you should see the general rule for diagonal matrices. Why (knowing that $M$ is Hermitian) is that enough?

Comment: @impopularGuy, it is not necessary for the eigenvalues of $I+hM$ to be positive. Take $M$ as negative of the $M$ that John Hughes introduced with $h=10$.